# Trying to update files on ubuntu through update-manager just fails

Tags: 16.04, updates, update-manager

I'm running 16.04 LTS, and I get "Failure downloading package files." (free translation, my distro is in Portuguese).

I've tried [this](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiygI2c6ezZAhVCFJAKHQ-EAO8QFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F73997%2Fhow-do-i-fix-a-failed-to-download-package-files-error&usg=AOvVaw1Stq5ngEpD24M2WogWMk-U) solution, but whenever I click Okay it asks me to reload. Then, when it tries to reload, it fails again with the same error.

This is the output error:

```
W:An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EFDC8610341D9410, W:https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease: Signature by key AAC9264309E4D717441DB9527373B12CE03BEB4B uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1), W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/osmoma/audio-recorder/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file., W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EFDC8610341D9410, E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/osmoma/audio-recorder/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found, W:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I need some help as I'm in need of updating some files and preparing for the April upgrade.

Comment: This is still as problematic, any new tries result in the same error.